# How to use relative Form.Top

Tags: c#, winforms, border

I'm trying to make an application in C# and when i try relating a control to `this.Top` it keeps adding the distance between the Form and the Screen's edge. What should i do so I could use the top of the Form as Top?

Part of Code:

```
 if (Cursor.Position.Y > (this.ClientRectangle.Top + pCsuszka2.Height / 2) && Cursor.Position.Y < (this.Height -  pCsuszka2.Height / 2))
        {

            pCsuszka2.Top = Cursor.Position.Y - (pCsuszka2.Height / 2);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in one of the mouse event handlers, you can use the MouseEventArgs parameter.  It seems to give you relative position on the form.

```
   private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = e.X.ToString() + ", " + e.Y.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped (Would rep you up if I could)